# Removing duplicate rows from different table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table and I would like to get only unique rows from one those tables.

On the following example, I need the list of application_id which have no duplicate name.

Table appName

| app_id | app_name |
| --- | --- |
| APP001 | a |
| APP002 | b |
| APP003 | c |
| APP004 | d |
| APP005 | f |

Table tbl_application_detail

| app_id | em_id |
| --- | --- |
| APP002 | 2424 |
| APP003 | 2424 |

Table that I expectation

| app_id | app_name |
| --- | --- |
| APP001 | a |
| APP004 | d |
| APP005 | f |

I am new SQL I don't know how make this code

```
SELECT application_id,application_name FROM appName 


SELECT application_id,em_id FROM tbl_application_detail WHERE em_id=2424
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can try using the following left anti-join approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY em_id) cnt
    FROM tbl_application_detail
)

SELECT t1.app_id, t1.app_name
FROM appName t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.app_id = t1.app_id
WHERE COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) <= 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: When I LEFT JOIN my Data 7rows but is show only 6 rows and when i try to use Left anti Join I meet this error : 'ANIT' is not a recognized join option.

Comment: It sounds like you're not running my code.  Check my demo link where my query is working using your provided sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Sub query (Mysql & SQL Sever) as well..

```
select * from appName where app_id not in (select app_id from tbl_application_detail)
```

or
Joins (SQL Sever)

```
select apn.* from appName apn full outer join tbl_application_detail tad 
on tad.app_id = apn.app_id 
where apn.app_id is null or tad.app_id is null
```

[image: Result]

[result](https://dbfiddle.uk/0HhTGy5V)